# DirectoryInfo.MoveTo - "Source and destination path must have identical roots. Move will not work across volumes."

Tags: c#, directoryinfo

I'm trying to figure out what is going on here.  I have a routine that looks at all the directories in a directory and removes any non numeric values from the first part of a directory name.  For some reason when it goes to do the MoveTo I'm getting the "Source and destination path must have identical roots.  Move will not work across volumes."  But I'm only providing the new name as the parameter.  So the directory might be "007A Raby" and the new name passed into MoveTo would be "007 Raby".  Anybody have any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

```
    private void RenameSubs(string directory)
    {
        try
        {
            if (Directory.Exists(directory))
            {
                var parentDI = new DirectoryInfo(directory);

                foreach (var di in parentDI.GetDirectories())
                {
                    var spaceLocation = di.Name.IndexOf(' ');
                    var changed = false;

                    if (spaceLocation > 0)
                    {
                        var oldName = di.Name;
                        var subPartA = di.Name.Substring(0, spaceLocation);
                        var subPartB = di.Name.Substring(spaceLocation, di.Name.Length - spaceLocation);

                        for (int i = subPartA.Length - 1; i > 0; i--)
                        {
                            if (subPartA[i] < '0' || subPartA[i] > '9')
                            {
                                subPartA = subPartA.Substring(0, i);
                                changed = true;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                        if (changed)
                        {
                            if (!Directory.Exists(Path.Combine(directory, subPartA + subPartB)))
                            {
                                var newName = subPartA + subPartB;
                                di.MoveTo(newName);
                                txtOutput.Text += "Renamed " + oldName + " to " + di.Name + "\r\n";
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                txtOutput.Text += "Error " + oldName + " already exists " + "\r\n";
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            txtOutput.Text += "Ignored " + di.Name + "\r\n";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }   
        }
        catch (System.Exception excpt)
        {
            txtOutput.Text += "Error " + excpt.Message + "\r\n";
            Console.WriteLine(excpt.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can post a few lines of codes to replicate the error (*Source and destination path must have identical roots. Move will not work across volumes.*) instead of making us to read all of the unrelated codes. How about posting a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: Use the debugger and look at the value of `newName`. I will bet it's not what you expected it to be. Also on a more general note: use the `System.IO.Path` class to manipulate directory and file names (intead of direct string operations); and for heaven's sake don't compare bool expressions to literals...I mean, it's legal and it works, but it's less readable than just writing `if (!Directory.Exists(...))`

Comment: Peter, I've run through the debugger and newName is exactly what I expected "007 Raby" and the di.Name property is "007A Raby".  I won't argue the readability of the Exists == false but how is that comparing a literal?

Comment: LB, I thought this was a small as SSCCE as I thought was appropriate.  My guess is this has something to do with the collection returned from GetDirectories becuase I've run through a small sample that just uses a single di to do the same thing and could not replicate the problem.  So I felt it necessary to include everything I did.

Comment: So with some more testing the failure has something to do with the application path and the directory location.  The code above works as long as I point it to the same drive that the application runs on.  But as soon as directory points to another drive it fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after trial and error I figured out how to fix it.  when a "relative path" is passed into DirectoryInfo.MoveTo it doesn't use the Parent Path but the application path.  So when I said it worked because it was on the same drive as the application I missed that it renamed the folders to the application folder.  To fix this I needed to pass in an absolute path to the MoveTo method.  Here is the code change needed inside the "if (changed)" code block to have this work:

```
    var newName = Path.Combine(directory, subPartA + subPartB);

    if (!Directory.Exists(newName))
    {
        di.MoveTo(newName);
        txtOutput.Text += "Renamed " + oldName + " to " + di.Name + "\r\n";
    }
    else
    {
        txtOutput.Text += "Error " + oldName + " already exists " + "\r\n";
    }
```

Hope this helps somebody else.