# Move Directory to another directory using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have one folder that has below location
"E:\New folder\ftp\data\666\pdffiles" and destionation path "C:\Users\arun\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ShopFloorApp\data\666\pdffiles". So i need to move all files from source to destination folder. in which case final directory form source(\data\666\pdffiles) need to same as destination(\data\666\pdffiles).

And i am tried with following one

```
string sourceDirectory = "E:\New folder\ftp\data\666\pdffiles"
 string destinationDirectory = "C:\Users\arun\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ShopFloorApp\data\666\pdffiles"
            Directory.Move(environmentVariable,localdirectory);
```

It shows error as **"Source and destination path must have identical roots. Move will not work across volumes."**

So kindly give your suggestion.

Comment: May be here you find.
`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26557614/directoryinfo-moveto-source-and-destination-path-must-have-identical-roots-m`